# How to assign a value to dynamic associative array in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

Say we have Bash 4 script like this:

```
1: arr='my_array';
2: declare -A "${arr}";
3: my_array[foo]='This is foo';
4: arrfoo="${arr}[foo]";
5: echo "${!arr}";
```

And the output is:

```
This is foo
```

But note, that thou the array `my_array` was declared dynamically (line 2), I've assigned value (under index `foo`) using it's direct name (line 3).

I can't find the syntax to assign value to associative array via dynamic name (I mean via `${arr}` variable in this case). Is that possible, since you can can declare arrays dynamically? Constructs like:

```
declare -A "${arr}"=(
    [foo]='This is foo'
);
```

just don't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `declare` by itself:

```
$ arr=my_array
$ declare -A "$arr"
$ declare "$arr[foo]=bar"
$ echo "${my_array[foo]}"
bar
```

This provides the indirection you need. The argument `$arr[foo]=bar` is expanded to `my_array[foo]=bar`, which is a valid assignment expression to be processed by `declare`.

Comment: How would you do it if the key is something that needs to be quoted? example: `declare "$arr[$key]=$val"` where `$key` is a mac address. I've tried every quoting trick I can come up with

Comment: What do you think needs further quoting?

Comment: Well, it wasn't a quoting issue, more a scoping issue. If trying to do the above in a function with a global associative array, `declare` needs the `-g` flag to assign to it, or it will try to create a local indexed array by the same name, and 'cast' the key to a numerical value by evaluating it as an arithmetic expression. Since any "key" that's a valid variable name will evaluate to 0, it will not report any error, but a mac address is not, so bash reports the error token as the address with the first two hex digits stripped, leading me to believe quoting was the issue.